# How to eliminate fonts which are not used to reduce release build

Tags: react-native, build, fonts, package.json, release-builds

[Apk Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgxOE.jpg)

package.json includes

*"rnpm": {
"assets": [
"./assets/fonts"
]
}
"react-native-vector-icons": "9.2.0",*

Comment: You can specify which fonts to be copied in build.gradle file https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-gradle-recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can go in library and comment the line if needed and [patch library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) so that fonts won't be included neither in iOS or Android builds

That's what I did when I faced issue with same library :)